# Transform and sort different date formats

Tags: xml, sorting, date, datetime, xslt

I have the task to transform a generated XML file using different date formats
as sort criteria. Being new to XSLT I wonder if it's possible using a single transformation unify the date formats and sort.

An example for source XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<summary>
    <incoming>
        <delivery incDate="2013-11-08"/>
    </incoming>
    <outgoing>
        <delivery outDate="20131108"/>
    </outgoing>
    <repairs>
        <repair repairDate="2013-11-08 11:25:34"/>
    </repairs>
</summary>
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<summary>
    <actions>
        <action type="incoming" dateTime="2013-11-08 00:00:00"/>
        <action type="repair"   dateTime="2013-11-08 11:25:34"/>
        <action type="outgoing" dateTime="2013-11-08 23:59:59"/>
    </actions>
</summary>
```

What did I do?

1. Unify all date formats.
2. Append a time 00:00:00 on all childs of `<incoming>`.
3. Append a time 23:59:59 on all childs of `<outgoing>`.
4. Add attribute with name of parent.
5. Sort output by date.

Comment: I haven't tried because (to be honest) I haven't got a clue if it's possible to do with a single XSLT transformation. I did it using C++ and pugixml... but I wanted to try something new which doesn't rely on a 2nd language.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you able to use?  This _is_ possible if you're limited to 1.0 but will be quite a bit simpler in 2.0 or later.

Comment: I can use both versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 this is quite straightforward as you can use a two-pass approach, first generate the required outputs and then sort them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <summary>
      <actions>
        <xsl:perform-sort>
          <xsl:sort select="@dateTime" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="summary/*/*" />
        </xsl:perform-sort>
      </actions>
    </summary>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="incoming/delivery">
    <action type="incoming" dateTime="{@incDate} 00:00:00"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outgoing/delivery">
    <action type="outgoing" dateTime="{substring(@outDate, 1, 4)}-{substring(@outDate, 5, 2)}-{substring(@outDate, 7, 2)} 23:59:59"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="repairs/repair">
    <action type="repair" dateTime="{@repairDate}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we're generating the output for each input element using the `apply-templates` and *then* sorting those generated elements with `perform-sort` using an XPath expression (`@dateTime`) relative to the generated XML rather than the original.

If you're limited to 1.0 this isn't an option, as you can only sort based on things in the input XML, not the generated output.  So we need to come up with a single XPath 1.0 expression that can handle any of the three date formats and produce a suitable sort key

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <summary>
      <actions>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="summary/*/*">
          <xsl:sort select="
             translate(
               concat(
                 @incDate, @outDate, @repairDate,
                 substring('000000', 6*not(@incDate) + 1),
                 substring('235959', 6*not(@outDate) + 1)
               ),
               '-: ',
               ''
             )" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </actions>
    </summary>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- the other three templates are unchanged -->
```

This uses a number of tricks, most notably the

```
substring('000000', 6*not(@incDate) + 1)
```

which relies on a number of things:

- the argument of `not()` is treated as a boolean.
- when you treat a node set as boolean, an empty set is false and a non-empty set is true
- casting boolean to number gives 1 for true and 0 for false

so the effect is to return the string `000000` if the target node has an `incDate` attribute, and the empty string if it doesn't.  The final `concat` builds up a string that will look like `YYYY-MM-DD000000` for the `incDate`, `YYYYMMDD235959` for the `outDate` and `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` for the `repairDate`, the `translate` strips out all spaces, hyphens and colons to bring these three into a common format that can be compared lexicographically.

Comment: Thanks. Now I "only" have to fully understand it! :-) I'm sure I will... just takes some time. Just out of curiosity: Would a XSLT 1.0 solution have been much more complicated and is learning XSLT 1.0 still recommended?

Comment: @fhw72 it's possible in 1.0, but you have to sort the input nodes rather than the generated output, and the XPath language is much more limited so you have to use several idiomatic tricks to be able to build a usable sort key.  If you have the option of using 2.0 then take it, the 2.0 language (both XPath and XSLT) is far nicer than 1.0, but unfortunately many XSLT processors are stuck on version 1.0.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll do as you suggest and stick to 2.0! It's interesting to see these two different approaches and I'm eager to learn (or at least understand) both possibilities!